# Using Saxon, increment or decrement the global variables in XSLT

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan

I want to use a counter to increment and decrement the value in XSLT. I am able to achieve this using Apache Xalan,  but now I want to achieve the same using Saxon.

My XSLT script for Xalan looks like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
                xmlns:result="http://www.example.com/results"
                extension-element-prefixes="result">

    <lxslt:component prefix="result" functions="incr dcr">
        <lxslt:script lang="javascript">
            var count = 0;
            function incr() {
              count++;
              return count;
            }

            function dcr() {
              count--;
              return count;
            }
        </lxslt:script>
    </lxslt:component>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        a)<xsl:value-of select="result:incr()"/>
        b)<xsl:value-of select="result:incr()"/>
        c)<xsl:value-of select="result:dcr()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output is:

```
a)1
b)2
c)1

------------------------- my use case using saxon -------------------
This is my sample data.xml file. I want to transform this to html file.

<entity>
  <record>10</record>
  <record>15</record>
  <record>19</record>
  <record>7</record>
  <record>4</record>
  <record>14</record>
  <record>24</record>
<entity>

I want to implement a counter for line-number and want to increment the counter and print the line-number
my expected outputs:

 case 1: If record values > 14, then my output should have line-number with value as.
 line-num  value    
  1        15
  2        19
  3        24

 case 2 : If record values < 14, then my output should have line-number with value as.
 line-num  value    
  1         10
  2         7
  3         4

My other use case :

<entity>
  <record>10</record>
  <record>15</record>
  <record>19</record>
  <record>7</record>
  <record>20</record>
  <record>14</record>
  <record>24</record>
    <entity>
       <record>30</record>
       <record>3</record>
    </entity>
</entity>
<entity>
  <record>5</record>
  <record>17</record>
  <record>19</record>
  <record>6</record>
  <record>70</record>
  <record>9</record>
  <record>35</record>
    <entity>
       <record>15</record>
       <record>2</record>
    </entity>
</entity>


This is my other use case, first <entity> record value > 15 and in second <entity> record value < 10, and my <entity> can grow bigger where i have to show only some record based on condition.

 line-num  value 
    1        19 
    2        20  
    3        24
    4        30 
    5        5
    6        6
    7        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use Javascript in Saxon as far as I know.

If you want to use an assignable and changeable variable in Saxon 9 (EE or PE) then you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon mf"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="counter" as="xs:integer" select="0" saxon:assignable="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:incr" as="xs:integer">
        <saxon:assign name="counter" select="$counter + 1"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$counter"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:decr" as="xs:integer">
        <saxon:assign name="counter" select="$counter - 1"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$counter"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
        a)<xsl:value-of select="mf:incr()"/>
        b)<xsl:value-of select="mf:incr()"/>
        c)<xsl:value-of select="mf:decr()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See the warnings and notes in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/assign.html however on attempts to introduce side effects. You might want to edit your question to explain your XML input and the desired output and why you think you need such a counter variable, hopefully we can then show a pure XSLT 2.0 solution instead of using an assignable variable.

As for your requirement to process and number certain input elements, the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="entity">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="record[. > 14]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="record[. &lt; 14]"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <line-num>
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </line-num>
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </value>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when run against the input

```
<entity>
    <record>10</record>
    <record>15</record>
    <record>19</record>
    <record>7</record>
    <record>4</record>
    <record>14</record>
    <record>24</record>
</entity>
```

outputs

```
<root>
   <record>
      <line-num>1</line-num>
      <value>15</value>
   </record>
   <record>
      <line-num>2</line-num>
      <value>19</value>
   </record>
   <record>
      <line-num>3</line-num>
      <value>24</value>
   </record>
   <record>
      <line-num>1</line-num>
      <value>10</value>
   </record>
   <record>
      <line-num>2</line-num>
      <value>7</value>
   </record>
   <record>
      <line-num>3</line-num>
      <value>4</value>
   </record>
</root>
```

Other options are using e.g. `xsl:number count="entity[. &lt; 14]"`.

As for your latest requirement, I think you can still handle that using `position()` as long as you select the elements you want to process, e.g. the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/entity[1]//record[. > 15], /root/entity[2]//record[. &lt; 10]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', ., '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the input

```
<root>
    <entity>
        <record>10</record>
        <record>15</record>
        <record>19</record>
        <record>7</record>
        <record>20</record>
        <record>14</record>
        <record>24</record>
        <entity>
            <record>30</record>
            <record>3</record>
        </entity>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <record>5</record>
        <record>17</record>
        <record>19</record>
        <record>6</record>
        <record>70</record>
        <record>9</record>
        <record>35</record>
        <entity>
            <record>15</record>
            <record>2</record>
        </entity>
    </entity>
</root>
```

outputs (with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9)

```
1 19
2 20
3 24
4 30
5 5
6 6
7 9
8 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the soultion.

Comment: I have gone through the Saxon documentation yesterday and able to figured it out and tried my sample.

Comment: "hopefully we can then show a pure XSLT 2.0 solution instead of using an assignable variable", I want control over the counter, for the purpose of increment/decrement with any integer value.

Comment: @Rohit, yes we know you want control over the counter. The question is why? What is the transformation trying to achieve? If you tell us what the input and output are, and how they relate, then we can teach you how to implement the transformation in a more XSLT-friendly way.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I did update my use case in the question.can you help me out with this.

Comment: @RohitThakur, I have added an XSLT sample that might help, it processes the elements you are interested in and outputs `position()`. You could also use `xsl:number` if needed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, position() and xsl:number will determine the position of current node in source.This will not work in my use case that I had updated again which is complex than previous one and can grow bigger.

Comment: @RohitThakur, `position()` gives you the position in the current processed sequence, not (necessarily) in the source. And `xsl:number` allows you as well to select the pattern and/or level of selection. I have edited the answer again and provided a sample using `position()` for your latest edit. If you have further questions then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

(Responding to the expanded description of the problem)

The key thing to appreciate is that this problem requires sequential processing of the `record` elements, in document order. This means it can't be achieved in a processor-independent way with xsl:for-each or xsl:apply-templates because these are not guaranteed to process the elements one at a time in order (recent versions of Saxon, for example, will process elements in parallel using multi-threading, and the spec allows this; this makes any attempt to update global variables ineffective).

The classic way to process elements sequentially is using head-tail recursion. Write a template or function that takes the sequence of `record` elements as a parameter, and the current line number as a second parameter. If the list of records is non-empty, then (a) process the first `record` in the list, and (b) call yourself recursively to process the rest of the list, passing the new value of the line-number.

It can be a bit mind-blowing to write code in this way the first time you try it, but it soon comes naturally.

In XSLT 3.0 there's a new construct xsl:iterate that looks more like a conventional loop: when you enter the xsl:iterate body you pass initial values for its parameters, and each time you continue to the next iteration of the loop you can set new values for the parameters.

Comment: I had another use case where record elements can be children.pleas provide your thoughts on this. It is available in  "My other use case :" section in my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think SO works well when people keep adding new supplementaries to the question. It makes it very difficult for anyone coming along later to follow the thread, and it's difficult for others to see what has changed. Ask a new question, and refer to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript, using saxon extension instructions.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
                extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
                exclude-result-prefixes="saxon">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="0" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        a) <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
            <saxon:assign name="i" select="$i+1"/>
        b) <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
            <saxon:assign name="i" select="$i+2"/>
        c) <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
            <saxon:assign name="i" select="$i+3"/>
        d) <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Link : http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/extensions/instructions/assign.html